# case when blank check returning null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following DB structure:

[image]

I wanted it in single column like:

```
Param

-
-
AccountNo
AccountNo DueDate
```

For this i written case when query:

```
select

case when Param1 <>'' then 'Param1'+Param1 
+case when Param2  <>'' then 'Param2'+Param2   
+case when Param3  <>'' then 'Param3'+Param3  
+case when Param4  <>'' then 'Param4'+Param4 
+case when Param5  <>'' then 'Param5'+Param5

end  
end
end
end
end
'param'

from IVR_PPMaster
```

But this query is returning me all NULL values.

Please help me to obtain result.

Comment: Slight aside - why bother checking for empty string? If you append empty string to a string, it'll just be the string regardless. You may as well make it simpler on yourself and just say `Param1 + Param2 + ...`

Comment: actually its going to get used in my code thats why @Bridge see my edit

Comment: the reason that sql return u null result is because of u are using case + case, when using case + case, whenever any of them return false, then whole condition will be false, for your query, whenever there are any of the param is null, then whole condition false , that y return null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent it some you get (I've kept the first only the first three params)

```
select case when Param1 <>'' 
            then 'Param1'+Param1 + case when Param2  <>'' 
                                        then 'Param2'+Param2 +case when Param3  <>'' 
                                                                   then 'Param3'+Param3
                                                              end  
                                   end
       end
as 'param'
from IVR_PPMaster
```

It's obvious that if `Param1` is empty, this code will return NULL, since that is what `case` returns if none of the conditions are met.

Basically this code will only return a string if none of the params are empty. You'll need non-nested cases to get the correct result

```
select case when Param1 <>'' then 'Param1'+Param1
            else '' -- this is needed because adding a null to a string yields null
       end
        + case when Param2  <>'' then 'Param2'+Param2 
               else ''
          end
        + case when Param3  <>'' then 'Param3'+Param3 
               else ''
          end
as 'param'
from IVR_PPMaster
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NullIf()` function with `IsNull()/Coalesce()` like below:

```
Select coalesce(nullif(param1,''),'') + coalesce(nullif(param2,''),'') + ... + 
       coalesce(nullif(param5,''),'') newColName
From yourTable
```

For *your case* just a null check like below may be enough:

```
Select coalesce(param1,'') + coalesce(param2 + ' ','') + ... + 
       coalesce(param5 + ' ','') newColName
From yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

try 
select  ISNULL(ColumName,' ') + ISNULL(ColumName,' ') as tt from TableName

Answer (score 1):

just remove your addition case, whenever u using case + case, then condition is chain, so whenever there are null value in param1-param5, your query also will return u false, so just remove your addition case if you just want to check for param1 and sum up other param

```
select

case when Param1 <>'' then +Param1 
+Param2   
+Param3  
+Param4 
+Param5
else ' '
end
'param'

from IVR_PPMaster
```

sample is here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70bdb/3